# query concatenation in mysql by applying condition

Tags: php, mysql

Why this query is not working ?... is it possible this kind of query? I want to use this query to retrieve data from mysql database.. but it is not working..

```
<?php 
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','','informationdb');
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $countryid=$_POST['countryid'];    //from <select></select>
    $cityid=$_POST['cityid'];          //from <select></select>
    $locationid=$_POST['locationid'];  //from <select></select>
    $subjectid=$_POST['subjectid'];    //from <select></select>
    $degreeid=$_POST['degreeid'];      //from <select></select>
    $q=' ';
    if($countryid!='0'){
        $q="select * from tblinformation where countryid='".$countryid."' ";
    }
    if($cityid!='0'){
        $q.= "and cityid='"$cityid"' ";
    }
    else if($locationid!='0'){ 
        $q.= "and locationid='"$locationid"' ";
    }
    else if($subjectid!='0'){ 
        $q.= "and subjectid="$subjectid" ";
    }
    else if($degreeid!='0'){
        $q.= "and degreeid='"$degreeid"' ";
    }
    $rst=$mysqli->query($q);
}
```

Comment: $q="select * from tblinformation where countryid='$countryid' ";

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working" please?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: What if your `$countryid` variable is '0' you will have an incomplete sql statement. Add before this line `$rst=$mysqli->query($q);`  the command `var_dump($q);` and see what it shows.

Comment: It looks like delimiters around the strings might be the problem. Not sure if those id values are strings or numerics though.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `.` for string concatenation:

```
if ($cityid != '0') {
    $q .= "and cityid = " . $cityid . " ";
}
```

and similarly for the other parameters.

Also, if `$countryid` is 0, you never initialize `$q` with the `select * from tblinformation` clause. You should put this part of the query in `$q` outside all the conditionals.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519890/mysqli-filter-results-from-form-post/26520095#26520095 for a better structure for code that builds the `WHERE` clause dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are mixed up.

This: `$q.= "and cityid="$cityid" ";` and the other similar statements, should be giving you an error in PHP.

If `cityid` is a numeric field (e.g. INTEGER) then you should use:

```
$q.= " and cityid=$cityid ";
```

If you are comparing a text or date field then it should look like:

```
$q.= " and cityid='$cityid' ";
```

I threw spaces on both sides because extra spaces are fine, but missing a space would be bad, so play it safe.

For some troubleshooting, `echo $q;` before you execute the query so you can see what it ends up evaluating to.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine except that you are missing `.` for string concatenation.
see my testing table below

[image]

```
$mysqli=new mysqli('localhost','root','','data');

$countryid= 1;    //from <select></select>
$cityid= 2;          //from <select></select>
$locationid= 3 ;  //from <select></select>
$subjectid=4;    //from <select></select>
$degreeid=5;      //from <select></select>
$q=' ';
if($countryid!='0'){
    $q="select * from tblinformation where countryid='".$countryid."' ";
}
if($cityid!='0'){
    $q.= "and cityid='".$cityid."' ";
}
else if($locationid!='0'){ 
    $q.= "and locationid='".$locationid."' ";
}
else if($subjectid!='0'){ 
    $q.= "and subjectid='".$subjectid."'' ";
}
else if($degreeid!='0'){
    $q.= "and degreeid='".$degreeid."' ";
}
$rst=$mysqli->query($q);
$data = $rst->fetch_assoc();
while ($data != null) {
    echo $data['Location'];
    $data = $rst->fetch_assoc();
}
```

> outputs: Johannesburg